# Mongodb / nodejs issue on digitalocean ubuntu 18.4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, digital-ocean

I set up droplets with ubuntu 18.4 on digitalocean where i install nodejs and mongodb.

when i try to connect to my API throught nodejs, i receive this error when doing pm2 logs :

```js
0|index    | App is running at http://localhost:5000 in development mode
0|index    | test Press CTRL-C to stop
0|index    | 
0|index    | You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have 
forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
0|index    | App is running at http://localhost:5000 in development mode
0|index    | test Press CTRL-C to stop
0|index    | 
0|index    | You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have 
forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
0|index    | App is running at http://localhost:5000 in development mode
0|index    | test Press CTRL-C to stop
0|index    | 
0|index    | You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have 
forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:

/root/.pm2/logs/index-error.log last 15 lines:
0|index    |     at deprecated (internal/util.js:47:15)
0|index    |     at connect 
 (/var/www/xxx/xxx/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:179:3)
0|index    |     at connectOp (/var/www/xxx/xxx/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:283:3)
0|index    |     at executeOperation (/var/www/xxx/xxx/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
0|index    |     at MongoClient.connect (/var/www/xxx/xxx/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:168:10)
0|index    |     at Promise (/var/www/xxx/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:493:12)
0|index    |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
0|index    |     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/var/www/xxx/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:490:19)
0|index    |     at Mongoose.createConnection (/var/www/xxx/xxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:190:17)
0|index    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/xxx/xxx/index.js:6:30)
0|index    |     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
0|index    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
0|index    |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
0|index    |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
0|index    |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

Mongodb is running perfectly, and my nodejs code is like this :

```
const express     = require('express')
const session     = require('express-session');
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const path        = require('path')
const mongoose    = require('mongoose');
const connection  = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
const app         = (module.exports = express());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Lab", function (err) {
   if (err) console.error('Could not connect to mongodb.');
});
...
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
console.log(
  'App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode',
  app.get('port'),
  app.get('env')
);
   console.log('test Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
});
```

On console i can see the message :

```
0|index    | App is running at http://localhost:5000 in development mode
0|index    | test Press CTRL-C to stop
```

So i think my nodejs app is running fine but connection to mongodb has an issue, someone could helps me please?

**** UPDATE 
When i run : mongo on CLI i have this :

```js
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
Server has startup warnings: 
2018-08-04T09:56:28.449+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2018-08-04T09:56:28.449+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-08-04T09:56:28.449+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-08-04T09:56:29.619+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-08-04T09:56:29.619+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-08-04T09:56:29.619+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-08-04T09:56:29.619+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please share full error stack, these are last 15 only.

Comment: Also share the value of process.env.MONGODB_URI

Comment: which mongoose and mongo version are you using in digital ocean? Is the same as localhost?

Comment: @Er_sherlockian : MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017

Comment: make sure mongodb is up and running: `sudo ps -ax | grep mongo`  if not so: `/etc/init.d/mongodb start` or `/etc/init.d/mongod start` or `service mongodb start`

Comment: the first command gives : 
sudo ps -ax | grep mongo
 6234 ?        Ssl    3:36 /usr/bin/mongod --unixSocketPrefix=/run/mongodb --config /etc/mongodb.conf
32673 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mongo

Comment: ok, as I understand You try to connect using hardcoded uri, comment this line and check again: `const connection  = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.MONGODB_URI);`

Comment: could you please write here your mongodb, mongoose, nodejs version ? @ikalangita

Comment: could you please write here your mongodb, mongoose, nodejs version ? @ikalangita

Comment: Nodejs : v8.10.0 , db version v3.6.3, and mongoose@5.2.6

Comment: Hi, all, i resolved this by re-installing mongodb from this link : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04 
thanks for your help.
@num8er : yes commenting this line is the key too.